# When compiling following plsql procedure, I get error 'Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'CL' must be declared'

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

PLSQL procedure which declares a cursor 'CL' , a record 'MAN_TXN_REC' and a table of
those records 'man_txn_rec_table', the sql query inside the cursor executes properly but i am unable to compile this procedure.I do have some doubts here regarding bulk select into a table or records , that may be causing trouble here.

```
create or replace procedure myproc_123
is
    TYPE MAN_TXN_REC is record
    (
        man_txn_id   manual_transaction.manual_transaction_id%TYPE
       ,item_acc_id  manual_transaction.item_account_id%TYPE
       ,man_txn_req_id manual_transaction.manual_transaction_request_id%TYPE
       ,txn_amt manual_transaction.transaction_amount%TYPE
       ,txn_base_type manual_transaction.transaction_base_type_id%TYPE
       ,txn_status_id manual_transaction.transaction_status_id%TYPE
       ,txn_amt_curr_id manual_transaction.trans_amount_curr_id%TYPE
     );
    v_man_txn_rec MAN_TXN_REC;

    TYPE man_txn_rec_table is table of MAN_TXN_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_man_txn_rec_table man_txn_rec_table;

    cursor c1 is
        SELECT /*+ index(tran MANTRAN_TRANDTSTATUSISDEL_IDX) */  
        tran.manual_transaction_id
       ,tran.item_account_id
       ,tran.manual_transaction_request_id
       ,tran.transaction_amount
       ,tran.transaction_base_type_id
       ,tran.transaction_status_id
       ,tran.trans_amount_curr_id
        FROM manual_transaction tran
        WHERE item_account_id =
               ( SELECT item_account_id from item_account
                    WHERE item_account_id = tran.item_account_id
                    AND item_acc_type_id = 2
                )
           AND tran.transaction_status_id = 3
           AND tran.is_deleted = 0
           AND ( Nvl(tran.trans_date, SYSDATE) < SYSDATE OR
         Nvl(tran.post_date, SYSDATE) < SYSDATE
                   )
           AND ROWNUM < 50
           FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

BEGIN
     open cl;
     FETCH c1 bulk collect into v_man_txn_rec_table;
     FOR indx IN v_man_txn_rec_table.FIRST .. v_man_txn_rec_table.LAST
     LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_man_txn_rec_table(indx).man_txn_id);
     END LOOP;
     close c1;
END;
```

Comment: What part of compiler error message: `PLS-00201: identifier 'CL' must be declared` you don't understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the cursor as C1 (c one), not CL. Just change the line:

```
open cl;
```

For

```
open c1;
```

You refer to the cursor correctly --as c1-- in the rest of the code.

Comment: ok , i admit , it was a gross mistake commited by me , and now i have changed SQL Developer font to something more legible , ty anyway for pointing it out